# sort array of size n, the elements n-⌊√n⌋ left side of array are already sorted

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

> Giving array of size n, the elements n-⌊√n⌋ left side of array are
> already sorted.
>
> Suggest an algorithm with time complexity of θ(n) to sort the array.

I thought about using bubble sort of the rest of array which are √n, using time complexity of bubble sort we get (√n)^2 = θ(n).

now part 1 and part 2 are separately sorted. Then what? I thought next using merge sort about how its different if not use merges sorting from first without bubble sort?

Comment: Before merging two subarrays, both subarrays must be in sorted order. So you can use any sorting algorithm (e.g. bubble sort or merge sort) to sort the right subarray, and then merge left and right.

Comment: @user3386109 I mean lets assume first part is sorted as 1,3,5,8 and 2nd part 4,6,9. but using merge sort is O(nlogn)

Comment: merge **sort** is O(nlogn), but merging two sorted arrays is θ(n).

Comment: @user3386109 The copying step is `θ(n)`.  But you can get by in this case with `θ(sqrt(n) log(n))` comparisons by using binary search to figure out where to insert next.  If the comparison operation is expensive, this can be worthwhile.